# Is $x^{1/2}$ equal to a positive value only?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, radicals

My friend argues that $\sqrt{x}$ is unequal to $x^{1/2}$ because $\sqrt{x}$ can equal both negative and positive values, whilst $x^{1/2}$ can equal postive values only.

I tried to research it, but haven't found enough on that matter and I think that $x^{1/2}$ is simply only another way of representing $\sqrt{x}$. Which one of us is right?

Comment: If you want $\sqrt{\;}$ to represent the _square root **function**_, $\sqrt{x}$ can't be two (different) things at once. It is usually defined as (only) the _positive_ number $y$ such that $y^2=x$.

Comment: Within the realm of complex numbers, square roots and such get a bit subtle and there is a (quite specific) sense in which your friend is right. But within the realm of precalculus, $x^{1/2}$ is never negative and you're correct.

Comment: Basically this comes down to convention. We (as in mathematician of previous centuries) could have chosen the notation so that equation "$\sqrt(x) = -|\sqrt(x)|$" is true. But we didn't. Now we're using it to denote the positive solution $t$ to equation $x=t^2$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all :

> $$x^{1/2}=\sqrt{x}$$

Also, $\sqrt{x} ~(= x^{1/2})$ is always positive.

Note : $y^2=x$ and $y= \sqrt{x}$ are different.

The first one allows $y =\pm \sqrt{x}$ whereas the second one only refers to $y =+\sqrt x$

Answer (score 2):

The convention for positive real numbers is that $x^{1/2} \equiv \sqrt{x}$ denotes the *positive* square root of $x$, hence why, for example, the quadratic formula has the $\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}$ in the numerator. The same is true for $x^{\alpha}$ for $\alpha$ not an integer (so this includes $1/2,1/3,\pi, \log{2}$ and so on).